# How do you find the least value when an inverse trigonometric function is in the denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

> The function:
>
> $f(x)=\frac{4\pi^2}{3\arccos{(x^4-2x^2)}}+\frac{5\pi}{3}$
>
> If $B=\frac{m}{\pi}$
>
> where $m$ is the minimum value which $f(x)$ can take. Find the value of $B$.
>
> The choices given in my book are as follows:
>
> $\begin{array}{ll}
> 1.&4\\
> 2.&3\\
> 3.&5\\
> 4.&2\\
> \end{array}$

Gee, I'm confused on exactly what should I do here to solve this problem. Can someone help me here?. I think it has to be greater than $\frac{5\pi}{3}$ because that's a vertical shift for that function. But I don't know how to get the range here.

Comment: What’s the maximum value of $\arccos(x^4-2x^2)$?

Comment: @Tavish That would be $\pi$ if I recall correctly. Then this would meant that the result would be $\frac{9\pi}{3}=3\pi$ then following what it is being asked this would be the answer to be $3$. Am I correct with this conclusion?.

Comment: That’s correct.

Answer (score 0):

$x^4-2x^2=x^2(x^2-2) \ge -1$, and it takes value the value $-1$ when $x^2=1$.

As $x^2=1$, $\arccos(x^4-2x^2)$ has the largest value of $\pi$. Hence $$m=\frac{4\pi^2}{3\pi}+\frac{5\pi}{3}=\frac{9\pi}{3}=3\pi$$

Hence you are right, $$B=\frac{m}{\pi}=3.$$